# AWS StepFunctions: prefix input string

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

Using TypeScript and CDK, how do I define a task that prefixes one of the fields of the input and keeps the rest unchanged?

Input:

```json
{
  "field1": "foo",
  "field2": "bar"
}
```

Expected output:

```json
{
  "field1": "baz_foo",
  "field2": "bar"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a [Pass](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions.Pass.html) task and [intrinsic function](https://states-language.net/spec.html#appendix-b) States.Format.

```js
  const addPrefix = new sfn.Pass(this, 'AddPrefix', {
    parameters: {
      'field1.$': "States.Format('{}{}', 'baz_', $.field1)",
      'field2.$': '$.field2',
    },
  });
```